# Why does HotSpot need register allocation?

Tags: java, llvm, jvm-hotspot

Here's what I have read about the JVM. HotSpot is stack based and Dalvik is register based. If HotSpot is stack based, why do we need t have register allocation done once we have IT respresentation of code into Blocks?

Also, where does llvm fit into this? I read that we can use llvm core and backend for java source code. Does HotSpot use LLVM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HotSpot is not stack-based, the standard java *bytecode* is. HotSpot is an optimizing runtime which is allowed to use any trick imaginable to quickly execute code implementing the operational semantics of the stack-based machine defined by the JVM specification. Since all relevant CPU architectures are register-oriented, naturally HotSpot will exploit that and use register allocation.

HotSpot does not use llvm, it is an independent development. As far as I can see, there is an llvm-based JVM implementation called J3, unrelated to HotSpot.

Comment: http://markfaction.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/stack-based-vs-register-based-virtual-machine-architecture-and-the-dalvik-vm/ Based on what is mentioned here, I gather that there are mostly 2 VM architectures and HotSpot is stack based, the same way Dalvik is register based. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes, that is incorrect, or at least imprecise. Dalvik defines its own bytecode model which is register-based whereas HotSpot uses the standard bytecode which is stack-based. That doesn't make the JVM runtimes in question either stack- or register-based, no more than the fact that they can e.g. both run Clojure code makes them list-oriented.

Comment: Specifically, that article confuses *implementation* with *specification*. The Java standard *specifies* a stack-based virtual machine, it doesn't *implement* it. Likewise, the Android runtime specifies a register-based virtual machine and dalvik is a runtime which implements it. An implementation of a stack-based virtual machine does not itself need to be stack-based---and the fact is, it isn't.

Comment: Marking this answer as accepted. Clears my confusion. Thank you for your inputs!

Answer (score 1):

Modern CPU use multiple registers and to turn byte code into machine code, they have to use those registers.

The LLVM is a virtual machine for interaction with the OS.  HotSpot doesn't use LLVM though it has been suggested a few times.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "to turn byte code into machine code"? Since the compiler is in itself a program after all, it will use both native memory and registers to do its job. I thought the register allocation is is for the source code itself. If you have i=j+1 then move i to a register, load j, add 2 and so on. In this context, there is no stack being used but HotSpot is stack based. Here stems my confusion and hence this question.

Comment: The `javac` compiler checks validity, the JIT doesn't the actual compiling to machine code.